# searching a list for objects with same date

Tags: scala

I'm spinning a bit on searching a list using find, find with pattern matching, filter, foldLeft  (as well as using Joda for date equality).

I need to search a list of objects and find matches with the same date as a different object.

```
case class DD(time: Date, value: Double)
case class UT(time: Date, name: String, value: Double)
```

Given a list of UTs

```
var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
var utList = Seq(UT(sdf.parse("2012-02-11"), "adf", 1), UT(sdf.parse("2012-02-13"), "adf", 2),UT(sdf.parse("2012-02-16"), "addf", 3)
```

Most efficient way to find all UTs with matching DD.time?

Or, even better, split the list into two sublists where one list contains no matches and the other list contains UTs with matching DD.time?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you mean by "matching DD.time". Do you have an instance of `DD` and you want the `UT`s with machine `time` fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `utList.filter(ut => ut.time == dd.time)` to get all matching time

use `utList.partition(ut => ut.time == dd.time)` to partition.

Given that dd is an instance of DD.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am missing something, but...:

```
val (matchingDate, notMatchingDate) =
  utList partition {_.time == sdf.parse("2012-02-13")}
```

If you just have a single `DD` instance `someDd`:

```
utList partition {_.time == someDd.time}
```